# WPF - Translate a point relative to MainWindow to it's coordinates relative to a child control

Tags: wpf, layout, wpf-controls, transform

Is it possible to translate a point relative to MainWindow to be relative to one of its child controls?  For example, say a control's upper left corner was located at 500, 500 relative to MainWindow what code would convert that number to (0, 0)?  I'd like the solution to be agnostic of the layout mechanism (i.e. not require me to parent the control in a Canvas and use the Top and Bottom methods).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`UIElement.TranslatePoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx). For example:

```
var translatedPoint = mainWindow.TranslatePoint(new Point(500, 500), childControl)
```